# NHibernate loop select

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm attempting to get data using NHibernate and database return the strange result.
Objects from standart examples: Product and Category.
When im trying to load object with `Get<Product>(id)`, Nhibernate loads infinite cascading loop of referenced entities. I need just single Product and referenced Category. 
Its normal NH behavior or im doing something wrong?

Comment: have you `override` `GetHshCode` and `Equals`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide us with your model and map. 
I think it's because both the reference and hasmany are not Lazyload